# Remove text between specific tags in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some text that goes like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor <code>sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,</code> sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut <code>laoreet dolore magna</code> aliquam erat volutpat.

I am trying to remove everything between each pair of "code" tags. I wrote a function that works well when there is only one pair of tags per cell, but it doesn't take care of multiple instances. Here is the desired output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor <code></code> sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut <code></code> aliquam erat volutpat.

How would you advise me to do?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to remove everything between the "code" tags?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is your desired output? Please add it to your post.

Comment: I just did it. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on macro recorder:

```
Sub Test()
    'working for selection replacing all <*> sections
    Selection.Replace What:="<*>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

**Edit** attempt 2, after comments from OP:

```
Sub Attempt_second()
    'working for selection replacing all <*> sections
    Selection.Replace What:="<*code>*<*/*code>", Replacement:="<code></code>", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

It will replace text into `<code></code>` removing additional spaces in between.

Comment: The OP wants to remove the text enclosed in HTML tags as well. This does not do that.

Comment: @Excellll, have you tried this before you down-voted? From `Lorem ipsum dolor < code>sit amet` you'll get `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`- isn't it right? What I'm missing (or you)?

Comment: Take a closer look at the OP's expected output. All the text between open and close tags should be removed as well.

Comment: @Excellll, take a closer look at the OP's sample before and after- they are not the same. OP just add different text, before and after are just different!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to modify this so that it looks only for the specific tags that are in my example? I only have other tags in my text that I want ignored by the macro.

Comment: @user1029296, just change `What:="<*>"` into `What:="<*code>"`

Comment: Ok, and you are sure that the fact that we do not specify that "<code>" is the opening tag and "</code>" is the closing tag, we will not have problems in case of several pairs of tags in the same cell?

Comment: Thanks. I tried the macro and there is the following error: "Application-defined or object -defined error." If I select the column before I run the macro, it says "400" but doesnt change anything.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure this macro will do what I am looking for. I updated the output so that it is clearer.

Comment: @user1029296, it is totally different situation... give me few sec. :)

Comment: @user1029296, see edition. I could make replacement into `<code></code>` removing additional white spaces, I hope it could works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code looks like its what I am looking for. However I still get an error box with a 400 message when I try to run the macro. Am I missing something? Am I supposed to modify anything in the macro or can I use it as is?

Comment: if you have your text in cells try to select that range and run this macro. try to select not the whole column. which version of excel you are running?

Comment: it is to specific to the format <code></code> format. this answer will ultimately lead other people to ask a slightly different question. You did answer the OP question though.

Answer (score 1):

This VBA function can be used to strip out open and close HTML tags and what they enclose. It uses regex, which should be OK in this limited usage (but [beware using regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/657668)).

```
Function stripEnclosed(strIn As String) As String
Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, AllMatches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, M As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim closeIndex As Long
tmpstr = strIn
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "<[^/>]+>"
Set AllMatches = re.Execute(tmpstr)
For Each M In AllMatches
    closeIndex = InStr(tmpstr, Replace(M.Value, "<", "</"))
    If closeIndex <> 0 Then tmpstr = Left(tmpstr, InStr(tmpstr, M.Value) - 1) & Mid(tmpstr, closeIndex + Len(M.Value) + 1)
Next M
stripEnclosed = tmpstr
End Function
```

Note: you'll have to add the 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5' reference to your VBA project.

If you only want to remove a certain tag (e.g. `<CODE>` and `</CODE>`) just replace the `re.Pattern = "<[^/>]+>"` line of the code with the following:

```
re.Pattern = "<CODE>"
```

Comment: it's too sophisticated, not needed in this situation!

Answer (score -1):

**KazJaw**'s answer is simple, elegant and seems to meet your needs.

I took a completely different approach:

```
Public Function StripHTML(str As String) As String

Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "<[^>]+>"
End With

StripHTML = RegEx.Replace(str, "")
Set RegEx = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove the text enclosed in HTML tags as well. This does not do that.