# VBA remove HTML tags from string only removes first character

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to remove everything from `'<'` to `'>'` but the following code only removes the first `'<'` in the string and keeps the rest of the HTML tags.

This is the code:

```
Sub SendHTTP()
    Dim myRequest As Object
    Set myRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    myRequest.Open "Get", _
    "http://tyda.se/search/test?lang[0]=en&lang[1]=sv"

    'Send
    myRequest.Send

    Dim Response, message As String
    Response = myRequest.ResponseText

    'Remove HTML tags
    message = Replace(Response, "<*>", " ", xlPart)


    'Display message
    MsgBox message

End Sub
```

I also tried using the accepted answer from this question but it still only removes the first `'<'`

[Remove text between specific tags in Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924311/remove-text-between-specific-tags-in-microsoft-excel)

Comment: Maybe look into Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument if you do this sort of thing a lot.   Basically you can do something like tag.innertext and be done with it.

Comment: I don't believe you can use an expression like you are doing as the 2nd argument in the `Replace` function. Have a look at using [regular expressions](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA Replace function cannot handle wildcards, but the Range.Replace method can. If you write the Response variable to a cell, run the Range.Replace method, and then read the cell value back into the message variable, it will accomplish what you are trying to do.

Sample code:

```
Sub SendHTTP()
    Dim myRequest As Object
    Set myRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    myRequest.Open "Get", _
    "http://tyda.se/search/test?lang[0]=en&lang[1]=sv"

    'Send
    myRequest.Send

    Dim Response, message As String
    Response = myRequest.ResponseText

    'Write Response to cell
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") 'Change this to a cell that is available for your code to use.
        .Value2 = Response
        'Strip HTML tags
        .Replace What:="<*>", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart
        'Read value back into variable
        message = .Value2
        'Clear cell
        .ClearContents
    End With


    'Display message
    MsgBox message

End Sub
```